# Clang macOS (Home Brew) linker error with iostream

Tags: c++, clang, linker-errors, iostream, cout

I wanted to test some C++20 features, so I downloaded the latest version of Clang (11) via home brew on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.
Everything works, except `std::cout`. I get a big linker error:

```
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in main.cpp.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main.cpp.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [cpp20_test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp20_test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp20_test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [cpp20_test] Error 2
```

If I use other parts of STL, like `vector` or `unique_ptr` or any type traits features, everything works, including new C++20 features like concepts.
Even `printf()` works just fine.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You need to download the latest command line tools for Xcode from Apple's developer website and install them. Then after that you need to enter the following command in your terminal:

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

That's all.