# Std::cout couldn't be found by the gcc linker MacOs

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker-errors

So I'm getting this **linking error** with gcc:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in main-a06879.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-a06879.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-a06879.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in main-a06879.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main-a06879.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main-a06879.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in main-a06879.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in main-a06879.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main-a06879.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in main-a06879.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main-a06879.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It can't seem to find the libraries responsible for all std namespace functions.
In case of my hello world program **std::cout** couldn't be found by the **linker**.
Also my code editor: Visual Studio Code complains about the same error.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;

}
```

What I've tried until now:

1. reinstalling the Xcode command line tools
2. following the answer to this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462973/clang-macos-home-brew-linker-error-with-iostream) with the same problem as me, also I don't use clang installed via home-brew but the version that comes with the Xcode command line tools

I don't know how this happened.
Perhaps I once blindly used some command from the internet in my shell or such
But perhaps is there some way to reset all of those library search paths or whatever creates this behavior.

Comment: Won't solve your problem, but thought you should know that apple aliases gcc to clang, so it's actually the clang compiler you are using here rather than gcc.

Comment: `g++` is the C++ compile driver. `gcc` is for C.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just followed advice from another discussion here on Stack Overflow and I just used "g++" instead of "gcc" as I'd previously done to compile my program